# where does the input split take place?

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

i have one doubt regrading how map reduce works in the end to end overflow.
First data will be stored in the form of blocks in hdfs.The input data along with the map function will be submitted to the resource manager.now resource manager allocates tasks to the node managers.i know that input split is done by the input format.i wanted to know where is this input format located.is the input split done before the task is assigned to the node manager or is it done after the task is assigned to the node manager.could you please clarify my confusion.I wanted to know this process in hadoop2

Answer (score 0):

> The input data along with the map function will be submitted to the resource manager.

The location of the data will be provided to the RM such that any reads will be placed first as NODE_LOCAL. The data itself is not moved off of a datanode until a remote read is required.

> where is this input format located

The class itself is on the paths shown by `hadoop classpath`. A split is not a separate data object, it's only about boundary marker within an HDFS file.

> is the input split done before the task is assigned to the node manager or is it done after the task is assigned to the node manager

Splits are computed before resources can be allocated. Number of splits determines number of mappers